Question about complex differentiable forms
I have to show that, if $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ is an open set and $u \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ with $\omega = \frac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z}} dx \wedge dy \in \Lambda^2(\Omega)$ (the set of 2-forms on $\Omega$) then $\omega$ is exact.
I don't understand what $\Lambda^2(\Omega)$ means because I've seen different variants, like $\Lambda^2(\Omega)$ and $\Lambda^2_\mathbb{C}(\Omega)$ and I don't know their definitions.
The $2$-forms from $\Lambda^2(\Omega)$ are of form $a(x,y) dx \wedge dy$, with $a:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ or they are of form $a(x,y) dx \wedge dy$ with $a:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$?
And I've also encountered two notations for smooth functions: $\mathbb{C}^\infty(\Omega)$ and $\mathbb{C}^\infty_\mathbb{C}(\Omega)$. First is for functions $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and second for functions $g:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$? Or I'm wrong...

Is this a problem from a textbook or assigned to you as homework? If it is from a textbook, does it not define the notation?

@Deane I found this problem on the internet 2-3 days ago. I can't find the source now. I found something that $\Lambda_\mathbb{C}^2(\Omega)$ is the complexified of $\Lambda^2(\Omega)$ in John Lee - Introduction to Complex Manifolds but I still don't understand how it works

I think that we can identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$, but then $\partial u / \partial \overline{z}$ is complex-valued. Shouldn't be real-valued to be in $\Lambda^2(\Omega)$?

Thank god that we have a source now. You should learn what complexification means.

It does not idenify $\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb R^2.$ In short,  it replaces the field $\mathbb R$ by $\mathbb C.$

So the function $u$ is complex valued, and instead of $\Lambda^2(\Omega)$ should be what I defined in my post like $\Lambda_{\mathbb{C}}^2(\Omega)$ for the statement to be ok. It's true?

If we want to understand things we should first forget the notation. How would you complexify the vector space $\mathbb R^2,?$ More about differential forms: this post. Finally: I do not  have that brand new book by Lee. Does the author not explain or give a reference what complexification of $\Lambda^2(\Omega)$ means?

$\mathbb R^2$ was a bad example. Complexify $\mathbb R^n.$

@KurtG. Umm. I don't think that I'm explained well. Example is from internet. In that book I found something that I think to be relevant (this term of complexification. But I don't know if it's really relevant or not)

Who knows what is relevant to something from  the internet you can't find anymore.

Everything is complex-valued, and you should learn what $\partial/\partial z$ and $\partial/\partial\bar z$ are, then write $d=\partial +\bar\partial$ and check that $\frac i2 dz\wedge d\bar z = dx\wedge dy$.
